# XPath addressing of UML stereotype inside XMI file

Tags: xslt, xpath, uml, stereotype

I have a problem with XSLT/XPath when parsing my UML file (XMI).

The following expressions behave differently ($thisId contains the xmi:id of the class to check whether it is enhanced by the stereotype 'revisioned' inside 'itechnical_Profile'):

1)

```
<xsl:value-of select="//*:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId]/@xmi:id"/>
```

gives me correct id '_16_5_1_29f0058e_1359051179028_158208_16339application2'.

2)

```
<xsl:value-of select="//itechnical_Profile:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId]/@xmi:id"/>
```

gives me no output at all.

3)

```
<xsl:value-of select="/xmi:XMI/*:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId]/@xmi:id"/>
```

gives me correct id '_16_5_1_29f0058e_1359051179028_158208_16339application2'.

I have checked with

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(/xmi:XMI/*:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId])"/>
```

that the node is named 'itechnical_Profile:revisioned'.

I have also checked with

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(/xmi:XMI/*:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId]/..)"/>
```

that the parent node is named 'xmi:XMI'.

**So why does 2) fail?**

With the stereotype 'UML_Standard_Profile:entity' it works flawlessly.

Is my understanding of '//' wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Shortening the XMI file would be quite some work ... so after some debugging I have come up with the following workaround:

```
<xsl:function name="itechnical_uml:enhancedByStereotype_revisioned" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="packagedElementNode" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="local-name($packagedElementNode)"/>
  <xsl:if test="($elementName != 'packagedElement')">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      Error: this is not a packagedElement!
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="($packagedElementNode/@xmi:type != 'uml:Class')">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      <xsl:text>Error: this is a packagedElement but not with xmi:type = 'uml:Class'!&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:variable name="thisId" select="$packagedElementNode/@xmi:id"/>

  <xsl:variable name="stereotypeID">
    <xsl:value-of select="root($packagedElementNode)//stereotype[@name = 'itechnical_Profile:revisioned']/@stereotypeID"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$stereotypeID = ''">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      <xsl:text>Error: unable to find xmi:id of stereotype 'itechnical_Profile:revisioned'!&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:variable name="resultSet" as="element()*" select="root($packagedElementNode)/xmi:XMI/*:revisioned[@base_Class = $thisId]"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$resultSet/@xmi:id != ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

Checking the 'xmlns:itechnical_Profile' definitions inside UML XMI and my XSLT scripts did not show up any problems.

Comment: Could you shorten your xml and xslt files to the shortest variant, when the problem appears yet and publish them here?

Comment: It sounds like the namespace declared in the source XML doesn't match that in your XSLT. Can you tell us what is the definition of `itechnical_Profile` in the source XML and in the XSLT?

Comment: Although I do not know what the real reason for the failing case is my workaround is fine enough and also works with 'UML_Standard_Profile:entity'. Maybe it is due to the fact that the stereotype is inside an external profile XMI file? Never mind ...

Comment: Please give us the line from the XML which says `xmlns:itechnical_Profile="..."`. Do you have the same defined somewhere in your XSLT?

Comment: "Shortening the XMI file would be quite some work.." Yes, but for us reading a huge bulk of code and searching there the 0.1% of the relevant place is quite some work, too. So here shortening the code to the stem of the problem is a norm here on SO. And, as you can see, very often it helps the questioner to see the root of the problem himself.

Comment: So, what is the question now?